# How to get all child inputs of a div element (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

HTML:

```
<div id="panel">
  <table>
    <tr>
       <td><input id="Search_NazovProjektu" type="text" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><input id="Search_Popis" type="text" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I need to select all inputs in the particular div.

This's not working:

```
var i = $("#panel > :input");
```

Comment: $("#panel").find(":input");

Answer (score 351, accepted):

Use it without the greater than:

```
$("#panel :input");
```

The `>` means only **direct** children of the element, if you want all children no matter the depth just use a space.

Comment: Interesting... Now I'm confused... The `:` is for pseudo-classes, isn't it? But we want to select an element type. Why the `:`?

Comment: @mnemosyn - This is another type of selector like `:checkbox' is, see here for details: http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/  And here's a more complete list of these: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/form-selectors/

Answer (score 88):

You need

```
var i = $("#panel input");
```

**or**, depending on what exactly you want (see below)

```
var i = $("#panel :input");
```

the `>` will restrict to children, you want all descendants.

EDIT: As Nick pointed out, there's a subtle difference between `$("#panel input")` and `$("#panel :input)`.

The first one will only retrieve elements of type input, that is `<input type="...">`, but not `<textarea>`, `<button>` and `<select>` elements. Thanks Nick, didn't know this myself and corrected my post accordingly. Left both options, because I guess the OP wasn't aware of that either and -technically- asked for inputs... :-)

Comment: So, :input will select all input/select/textarea fields? All at once?

Comment: Essentially, yes. The selector returns an array of matches, so I guess you could say it does it 'at once', though I'm not perfectly sure what you mean by that...

Comment: I mean, "all together" with just that selector.
":input selector Description: Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements."
Didn't know about it, I will use it from now on :)

Answer (score 53):

The 'find' method can be used to get all child inputs of a container that has already been cached to save looking it up again (whereas the 'children' method will only get the immediate children). e.g.

```
var panel= $("#panel");
var inputs = panel.find("input");
```

Comment: This was perfect for me - I am looping over elements using .each() which means within the loop I am accessing the current element using $(this). As a result, I am unable to perform a lot of what is otherwise suggested in the answers. - Instead I am able to do $(this).find("input"); Thanks.

Answer (score 38):

If you are using a framework like Ruby on Rails or Spring MVC you may need to use divs with square braces or other chars, that are not allowed you can use `document.getElementById` and this solution still works if you have multiple inputs with the same type.

```
var div = document.getElementById(divID);
$(div).find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea')
        .each(function() {
            $(this).val('');
        });
$(div).find('input:radio, input:checkbox').each(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).removeAttr('selected');
});
```

This examples shows how to clear the inputs, for you example you'll need to change it.

Answer (score 13):

here is my approach:

You can use it in other event.

```js
var id;
$("#panel :input").each(function(e){ 
  id = this.id;
  // show id 
  console.log("#"+id);
  // show input value 
  console.log(this.value);
  // disable input if you want
  //$("#"+id).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel">
  <table>
    <tr>
       <td><input id="Search_NazovProjektu" type="text" value="Naz Val" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><input id="Search_Popis" type="text" value="Po Val" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

```
var i = $("#panel input");
```

should work :-)

the > will only fetch direct children, no children's children
the : is for using pseudo-classes, eg. :hover, etc.

you can read about available css-selectors of pseudo-classes here: http://docs.jquery.com/DOM/Traversing/Selectors#CSS_Selectors

Comment: @henchman - `:input` is a selector as well, http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/form-selectors/ If he had a `<textarea>` or button `input` would not find it, `:input` would, so there is a difference.

Comment: +1 , so leaving out > will do the trick. now i also found it on the page i recommended....

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for, but might be what you were after.
I combined this fragment I regularly use in my projects:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

with the following to get a json string of my 'form' element names & values.

```
var form_data = JSON.stringify($('table#my-table :input').serializeObject());
console.log(form_data);

// Outputs
{"input_name_1":"My Cool Value","input_name_2":"Another cool value"}
```