# Gather inputs into JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Using this answer [How to get all child inputs of a div element (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402707/how-to-get-all-child-inputs-of-a-div-element-jquery) I fetch all Inputs inside a specific `<div>`.

I further want to send the inputs via ajax, the number of inputs is not fixed so instead of manually putting each input into the json data to send, I want to use `each()` and - here comes the point where I don't know - append *each* `name` and `value` to json.

```
$('#mydiv :input').each(function(k, v) {
    postData += [{ $(v).attr("name"): $(v).val() }]; 
}

$.post("url.htm", postData, function( data ) { /***/ });
```

There must be a tiny error inside this but I can't figure out.

Comment: What is the type of `postData` in your case ?

Comment: @Sniffer `postData` is JSON used by jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the [`serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) function is what you need:

```
$.post("url.htm", $('#mydiv :input').serializeArray(), function( data ) { /***/ });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to send postdata, try making an array first, and then you need to do like this

```
var postData=[];

('#mydiv :input').each(function(k, v) {
    postData.push({ $(v).attr("name"): $(v).val() }); 
}

$.post("url.htm", postData, function( data ) { /***/ });
```

A word of caution, when making POST call, do specify the 4th parameter as "json" in case the expected response is JSON.