# jquery I want to disable a div within a form based on hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the below hidden field  and I want to disable all the elements within a specific div based on the value of the hidden field.
Here is the hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" id="addincidentval" name="addincidentval" value="Add Incident"/>
```

The div id is `ehdiv` and it contains select, input text and check and textarea fields.

Below is the jquery function

```
$(function(){
    var addinc = $("#addincidentval").val();
    if(addinc =="Add Incident"){
        $("#ehdiv *").disable();
    }
})
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Maybe post the relevant HTML to be more precise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this jquery code

```
 $(function(){
    var addinc = $("#addincidentval").val();
    if(addinc =="Add Incident"){
        $("#ehdiv *").prop("disabled",true);
    }
})
```

Comment: This seems to work with the plain text boxes and the selects I have in this div but it is not disabling the buttons or the text box that uses the jquery datapicker plugin.

Comment: This one did it. Thank you.

Comment: great , no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#ehdiv").find('*').prop('disabled', true)
```

you can also try

```
$("#ehdiv :input").prop('disabled', true)
```

[How to select ALL children (in any level) from a parent in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648761/how-to-select-all-children-in-any-level-from-a-parent-in-jquery)

[How to get all child inputs of a div element (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402707/how-to-get-all-child-inputs-of-a-div-element-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

`:input` selects all input, textarea, select and button elements. more: http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

```
$(function(){
  var addinc = $("#addincidentval").val();
  if(addinc =="Add Incident"){
    $("#ehdiv :input").attr("disabled", true);
  }
})
```