# how to get elements in unhide div by serialize method

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown that, by changing it, 
some of the divs that contain the textboxes and selectboxes are hiding 
and only one of them is displaying.
How can I get the only inputs that are in the divs haven`t class "hide" by serialize() ?

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="student-section-2" class="hide">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <label class="control-label" for="">bases</label>
                <input id="base-2" class="form-control  bases"  alt="2" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2">
                <label class="control-label" for="">fields</label>
                <input id="field-2" class="form-control  fields"  alt="2" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <label class="control-label" for="">students</label>
                <input id="student-2" class="form-control  students"  alt="2" type="text">                                  
            </div>

    </div>
    <div id="bank-section-2" class="hide">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <label class="control-label" for="">accounts</label>
                <select id="financial-account-type-2" class="form-control  finan-acc-types" name="financial-account-type" alt="2">
                    <option value="">select</option>
                    <option value="1">s</option>
                    <option value="2">b</option>
                    <option value="3">p</option>
                    <option value="4">a</option>
                    <option value="5">h</option>
                </select>

            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="personal-section-2" class="">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <label class="control-label" for="">s</label>
                <input id="s-2" class="form-control  s"  alt="2" type="text">                                   
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <label class="control-label" for="">notes</label>
                <textarea id="note-2" class="form-control notes"  alt="2"></textarea>                           
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

for exapmle i want to get **personal-section-2** inputs!
tank you for your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can do two classes to a the div which you want to get.

```
         <div id="student-section-2" class="test hide">
```

then split the classes and check it whether it has second class as a hidden or not.

```
    $("#dropdownchange").change(function(){

        $("#btn").click(function(){
        $( ".test" ).each(function( ) {
      if($( this ).attr('class').split(' ')[1] =='hide')
          {
           alert("i am hide do nothing");
           }
      else
         {
         alert("i am not hidden");
           //here you can get your input 
          var el = $(this).find("input");
           alert(el.val());
          //for looping through multiple links you can see the follwoing question
          }


});
```

check this question.. [How to get all child inputs of a div element (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402707/how-to-get-all-child-inputs-) of-a-div-element-jquery

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ali.
But I want to get inputs inside every div without **hide** class name, not to show or hide them.
And more importantly, their number is much higher than this, and I do not want to get them with if and else.